# Jagged shards when rendering transparency in 3D

Tags: graphics3d

I'm using `Graphics3D` to display a large number of semi-transparent (and non-overlapping) spheres, but I keep getting weird artificial shards. Here's a minimal example:

```
data = Flatten[Table[{{x, y, z}, RandomReal[]^5}, {x, 1, 5}, {y, 1, 5}, {z, 1, 5}], 2]; 
Graphics3D[{RGBColor[0.3, 0.4, 0.8, #2], Sphere[#1, 0.45]} & @@@data]
```

The output is different each time, but typically contains jagged shards like the ones in the middle of this picture:

[image]

This must be a rendering problem, because I can't see how light regions could arise in the middle of the darker spheres. Does anyone know a way to fix this?